# Настроить вебсервер на WSL UNIX

Tags: linux, веб-сервер, apache2, wsl2

Установил на Win 10 WSL2 Uuntu 20.20
поставил в ней Apache2, SQL и PHP.
Нaстроил sites-evailable и если захожу через links на 127.0.0.1 - Вижу свой рабочий index.php (пока там прописано просто echo('прив');)

Но вот из windows не могу туда попасть через браузер и не понимаю куда копать, помогите, пожалуйста.
127.0.0.1 в Windows выдает "Сайт 127.0.0.1 не позволяет установить соединение"

На всех файлах в sites-available и на всех файлах в папке с проектом стоят права 7772

Comment: https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/4392

Comment: Не получается использовать этот метод.
Команда webdev не найдена и не могу найти информации по ней в интернете((((

Comment: какой ещё webdev??? суть проблемы — слушать надо не конкретный ip 127.0.0.1, а все адреса на всех интерфейсах: 0.0.0.0

Comment: Дошло, спасибо!